The difference between Sobolev Spaces written by Adams and Fournier in 2003 and Sobolev Spaces written by Adams in 1975
It seems that the book Sobolev Spaces written by Robert A. Adams and John F. Fournier in 2003 is the second edition of the book Sobolev Spaces written by Robert A. Adams in 1975. However, Chapter 7, Fractional Order Spaces, in these two books shows significant differences. Specifically, the first book (2003) deleted some characters of fractional Sobolev spaces from the second book (1975), while it also added some new descriptions of other fractional order spaces like Lorentz spaces, Besov spaces etc.
My question is, if you have read both books, could tell me if there are other significant differences between them?

The preface to the 2003 book mentions some of the differences (available on google books). It is described as a second edition of the 1975 book, but has some differences in presentation of certain material.
